# Nested array slicing

Tags: arrays, arraylist, julia

Let's say I have an array of vectors:

```
""" simple line equation """
function getline(a::Array{Float64,1},b::Array{Float64,1})
    line = Vector[]
    for i=0:0.1:1
        vector = (1-i)a+(i*b)
        push!(line, vector)
    end
    return line
end
```

This function returns an array of vectors containing x-y positions

```
Vector[11]
 > Float64[2]
 > Float64[2]
 > Float64[2]
 > Float64[2]
  .
  .
  .
```

Now I want to seprate all x and y coordinates of these vectors to plot them with plotyjs.

I have already tested some approaches with no success!
What is a correct way in Julia to achive this?

Answer (score 6):

You can broadcast `getindex`:

```
xs = getindex.(vv, 1)
ys = getindex.(vv, 2)
```

Edit 3:

Alternatively, use list comprehensions:

```
xs = [v[1] for v in vv]
ys = [v[2] for v in vv]
```

Edit:

For performance reasons, you should use `StaticArrays` to represent 2D points. E.g.:

```
getline(a,b) = [(1-i)a+(i*b) for i=0:0.1:1] 

p1 = SVector(1.,2.)
p2 = SVector(3.,4.)

vv = getline(p1,p2)
```

Broadcasting `getindex` and list comprehensions will still work, but you can also `reinterpret` the vector as a `2×11` matrix:

```
to_matrix{T<:SVector}(a::Vector{T}) = reinterpret(eltype(T), a, (size(T,1), length(a)))

m = to_matrix(vv)
```

Note that this does not copy the data. You can simply use `m` directly or define, e.g.,

```
xs = @view m[1,:]
ys = @view m[2,:]
```

Edit 2:

Btw., not restricting the type of the arguments of the `getline` function has many advantages and is preferred in general. The version above will work for any type that implements multiplication with a scalar and addition, e.g., a possible implementation of `immutable Point ... end` (making it fully generic will require a bit more work, though).