# Correct way to (un)zip arrays in Julia

Tags: list, julia, scatter

I was using the PyPlot library in Julia for plotting, and the scatter function seems to have a "little" inconvenience, namely, that only accepts the coordinates as two arguments: one array for all x values, and another for all y values, i.e.

```
scatter(xxs,yys)
```

with `x=[x1,x2,...]`, and `y=[y1,y2,...]`.

If I have a set or a tuple with points of coordinates, like,

```
A=([x1,y1],[x2,y2],...)
```

using pyplot/matplotlib directly in Python solves the inconvenience in one liner, as atested [here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519203/plotting-a-list-of-x-y-coordinates-in-python-matplotlib):

```
plt.scatter(*zip(*li))
```

but it seems that zip on Julia works completely different. Until now, I have come with following solution, but it seems quite inelegant:

```
x=[]
y=[]
for j in selectos
  append!(x,j[2])
   append!(y,j[1])
end

scatter(x,y, marker="o",c="black")
```

Is there a more "functional" or one-liner (or two liner) approach?

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41183481/6172490. However, the other question didn't specifically ask about `zip(A...)...`. So maybe this question motivates someone to write an efficient and generic `unzip` function :) See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13942.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, one can use the same approach in Julia, i.e., `scatter(zip(A...)...)`, but this is *very* slow for larger vectors and should be avoided.

Another possibility is to use `getindex.(A, i)` to get a vector of all `i`th elements of the vectors in `A`.

```
julia> A = [[i, 10i] for i=1:5]
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 10]
 [2, 20]
 [3, 30]
 [4, 40]
 [5, 50]

julia> getindex.(A,1)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> getindex.(A,2)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 10
 20
 30
 40
 50
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three approaches:

```
using PyPlot

A = ([1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8])

# approach 1
scatter(zip(A...)...)

# approach 2
B = hcat(A...)
@views scatter(B[1,:], B[2,:])

# approach 3
scatter([x[1] for x in A], [x[2] for x in A])
```

The first one is probably most functional style.

In the second one you get `B` which is easier to work with if you need to analyze the data; n.b. `@views` requires Julia 0.6, but it can be omitted.

The third is probably the simplest to understand.

Comment: And probably not very readable variant of third option in functional style: scatter(map(i -> map(x -> x[i], A),1:2)...).